# Passing sparkSession as function parameters spark-scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm in the process of generating tables using spark-scala and I am concerned about efficiency.

Would passing sparkSession make my program slower? Is it any slower than SparkSession.getOrCreate ?

I am using yarn as master.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No it won’t slow the process if passed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create Spark session once and pass around without losing any performance.
However it is little inconvenient to modify method signature to pass in a session object. You can avoid that by simply calling `getOrCreate` in the functions to obtain the same global session without passing it. When `getOrCreate` is called it sets the current session as default `SparkSession.setDefaultSession` ad gives that back to you for other `getOrCreat` calls

```
    val spark : SparkSession = SparkSession.builder
      .appName("test")
      .master("local[2]")
      .getOrCreate()

    //pass in function
    function1(pass)
    
    //obtain without passing
    
    def function2(){
    val s = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    }
```

Comment: when i sbt compile it complains about this syntax?

Comment: [error] /home/hadoop/score2/src/main/scala/comm_demo/Score2.scala:46:36: identifier expected but '.' found.
[error]   val spark = SparkSession.builder..getOrCreate()
[error]                                    ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed

Comment: You have 2 dots after builder, delete one

Comment: thanks!  did end up guessing it might be a typo in the answer code, worked great.